# Importing just types

Tags: typescript, firebase

With the Firebase Admin API you get typings from the @google-cloud/[namespace] where namespace could be `firestore`, `messaging`, `database`, etc.

Using **firestore** as the example. What I'd like to do is import *only* the type definitions, however if I add `@google-cloud/firestore` as a dependency I get everything (code and typings).

I considered the following:

- adding the dependency as a **devDependencies** so I could use the types but consumers of my library would not get the unused code.
- I also considered, keeping as a **dependency** but I wasn't sure how to import the interface definitions. I tried imports like below to no avail:

  import firestore from '@google-cloud/firestore/types';

I'm really eager to find some way -- outside of cutting-and-pasting -- to import the Admin API type definitions.

> **Note:** this is quite easy with the client-side API typings and ultimately what I want to be able to do is create interfaces that allow for libraries to write typed code that interacts with both client and admin libraries.